# Automapper conversion

Tags: c#, automapper

I have structure like below:

```
public class DetailsViewModel<T> where T : Standard
{
   public IList<T> OrderLines { get; set; }
}

public class Standard{}

public class InitialStandard : Standard {}

public class AlteredStandard : Standard {}

public DetailsViewModel<Standard> Construct<T, U>(bool isAltered, DirectOrder directOrder)
   where T : DetailsViewModel<U>
   where U : Standard
{
   if (isAltered)
      {
         var model = Mapper.Map<DetailsViewModel<AlteredStandard>>(directOrder);
         return model;
      }
      else
      {
         var model = Mapper.Map<DetailsViewModel<InitialStandard>>(directOrder);
         return model;
      }
}
```

Classes `InitialStandard` and `AlteredStandard` have the same properties that `Standard`. Differences are only in values which occurs in 2 different profiles.

Can someone tell why I got message like "Cannot implicitly convert type `DetailsViewModel<AlteredStandard>` to `DetailsViewModel<Standard>`" or "Cannot implicitly convert type `DetailsViewModel<InitialStandard>` to `DetailsViewModel<Standard>`"?

Comment: This is due to `DetailsViewModel<T>` not being [`Covariant`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/variance-in-generic-interfaces).  That could be fixed by declaring an interface `public interface DetailsViewModel<out T> where T : Standard`, but that makes the `IList<T>` unhappy, since it isn't also covariant.  Unfortunately, the whole variance, covariance, and contravariance thing hurts my brain.  I don't know if there is a good solution, though hopefully someone else will have an idea.